# jQuery .on() not working, while .live() does fine

Tags: jquery

I have this:

```
$("#socialsLogin").on("click", function() {
    var login = $("#socialsLoginField").val();
    var passwd = $("#socialsPasswordField").val();
    SocialsStart(login, password);
});
```

And this:

`<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="socialsLogin" class="button">Disconnected</a>`

And my click event is not firing up - what am I doing wrong? If I change .on() with .live(), everything works fine. But I don't want to use .live() since it is deprecated (and yes, I am using jquery 1.9)

**Edit:** It is not a duplicate. When I use `$(document).on("click", "#socialsLogin", function() {` it works everywhere on the page - I might click on an image and it fires up. Definitely not as intended. And `$(document.body).on("click", "#socialsLogin", function() {` doesn't work at all for me.

**Edit2:** Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JeDLW/1/

Comment: are you wrapping that code in a `$(document).ready(function() { ....` ?

Comment: @SamDufel: What? No. I am not so good with javascript so I even don't know what your code does. :)

Comment: @ojek - most likely, your javascript is running before the page is ready to have events bound to it.  Read this article - http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: @ojek start by removing `href="javascript:void(0)"` from your mark-up (you shouldn't add JS like this.. instead, use selectors in your script to target the desired elements), then have a look at the answers below..

Comment: @ojek Regarding your edit, you don't seem to get how `on` works. You should read my answer or try the code we suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace `live`, use `on` like this :

```
 $(document.body).on("click", "#socialsLogin", function() {
```

The jQuery set receives the event then delegates it to elements matching the selector given as argument. This means that contrary to when using `live`, the jQuery set elements must exist when you execute the code.

Note that this binding code should be executed in a `ready` callback :

```
$(function() {
     $(document.body).on("click", "#socialsLogin", function() {
         ...
     });
});
```

**EDIT :**

As I suspected, your fiddle shows that you use more than one element with the id `"socialLogin"`. That's the problem. Change the id of your fieldset.

Comment: Of course, binding it to `document.body` completely circumvents the advantage of using `.on()` over `.live()`

Comment: @SamDufel When the selector just points at the id, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @SamDufel you lose some of the advantage in terms of the delegation targets, but you still get the advantage of using a non-deprecated method

Comment: @SamDufel ...except that `.live()` is deprecated while `.on()` is not

Comment: @dystroy: Okay, I fired it up in a ready callback, and still, it works, but not when I click on an anchor tag, but it works on every click i make. Why? It's like the selector was whole document?

Comment: There might be a problem with your HTML... Are you sure you didn't get this id to another element ? Can you build a [fiddle](http://jsbin.com) ?

Comment: @dystroy: http://jsfiddle.net/JeDLW/1/

Comment: @ojek I changed your fiddle to import jQuery and use on instead of live : http://jsfiddle.net/dmu76/ . You see clicking the document doesn't launch the alert, only clicking the fieldset. EDIT : your problem is that your fieldset has the same id"socialLogin".

Comment: Well, that .live() was there by mistake, previously i had .on(). Anyways some magic happened and the thing is working, so thank you. :)

Comment: @dystroy Actually, it's not. The `fieldset` has the id `socialLogin` while the selector is targeting `socialsLogin` (notice the 's'), which is the anchor tag

Comment: @ojek http://jsfiddle.net/JeDLW/2/ This'll work

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#socialsLogin", function() {
    var login = $("#socialsLoginField").val();
    var passwd = $("#socialsPasswordField").val();
    SocialsStart(login, password);
});
```

Or you can simply use this:

```
$("#socialsLogin").click(function () {
    var login = $("#socialsLoginField").val();
    var passwd = $("#socialsPasswordField").val();
    SocialsStart(login, password);
});
```

Comment: Yeah this works, but not as intended, i might click on everything and it fires up. :D

Comment: Is `socialsLogin` element dynamically created?

Comment: No, but it is being hidden and showed up.

Comment: Please try the next code then...

Comment: Yes, .click() works fine just as .live() does. But I am curious why my .on is not working

Comment: @ojek please add the important mark-up and JS code to http://jsfiddle.net , then click "Save" and post the generated URL, and I'll have a look. Works for me, so there must be something wrong in your code...

Comment: @ojek http://jsfiddle.net/JeDLW/2/